# Configuring XKB fails

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, lxde, xkb

I am running LXDE on ubuntu 12.04, and I use two keyboard layouts (german and greek). My problem is that I cannot use the "AltGr" key of the German keyboard (it is the right "Alt"). It somehow collides with the "switch" option of XKB, so that when I press "AltGr", the keyboard switches to greek.

I only know how to correct this when I am in the terminal. I have added this in my .bashrc file:

```
setxkbmap -option -option grp:lwin_switch,grp:lalt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll de,gr
```

However, I dont know how to make this the default setting of LXDE. I tried to do it by inserting this in the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file:

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier "Keyboard1"
    Driver "Keyboard"
    Option "XkbRules" "evdev"
    Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
    Option "XkbLayout" "de gr"
    Option "XKbOptions" "grp:lalt_lshift_toggle,grp:lwin_switch,grp_led:scroll"
EndSection
```

It doesnt work. After rebooting, the old XKB settings are back from the dead.

Any ideas? Where does xkb get its default setting from?

Thanks
M.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I removed the setxkbmap command from the `.bashrc` file and added it to this file:

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

You have to put an `@` in the beginning of the line (I wonder why), so practically the line that I added looks like this:

```
@setxkbmap -option -option grp:rwin_switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll de,gr
```

Note that the commands in this autostart file are executed each time LXDE starts (for all users). If you need to do something like this only for one user, then use this file instead (no `@` needed in this case):

```
/home/*username*/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Would you accept your own answer as it does work for you. See [About]